# How to delete a user's sent command after bot's reply in discord.io

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.io

First of all, normal discord.js stuff seems to not work in my code.

So I want to make it so that the user calls the command, the bot replies and deletes the user's message ,that called the command, as well.

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '?') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
       
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'gw':
var gw = args.slice(1).join(' ');
var thumb = args[0];
let date = new Date();
            let smalldate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() +1) + ' | ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
               bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: `\n <@&${'806183931065401405'}>` + `\n` + `\n  __**Giveaway**__ `,
  embed: {
    color: 16580705,
    footer: { 
      text: 'Started On :  ' + smalldate,
    },
    thumbnail:{
url : thumb
    },
    title: gw,
    description: 'Hosted By: ' + user,
  }
});
bot.deleteMessage(message);
         }
}
});
```

Thank you from the core of my heart for any replies.

Comment: Try `message.delete()` instead of `bot.deleteMessage`. Also, arrow notation instead of a standard function is preferred.

Comment: How do I use message.delete() in arrow notation ?

Comment: I did not mean to use arrow in `message.delete()`. I told that you can use arrow during the event 'message'.

Comment: I would really suggest reading the [discord documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome). Also, watch some tutorials, you need to strengthen your base.

Comment: 1. I used arrow notation. 
2. message.delete() is not a function, it says in the console.

Comment: Take a look at my implementation.

Comment: Try to change your message to a Discord generated embed. See [embeds](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html).

Answer (score 2):

As I discussed in my comment, here are the changes:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {// arrow function
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) {
        body = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length)
        var args = message.content.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
       
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'gw':
var gw = args.slice(1).join(' ');
var thumb = args[0];
let date = new Date();
            let smalldate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() +1) + ' | ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
               message.channel.send({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: `\n <@&${'806183931065401405'}>` + `\n` + `\n  __**Giveaway**__ `,
  embed: {
    color: 16580705,
    footer: { 
      text: 'Started On :  ' + smalldate,
    },
    thumbnail:{
url : thumb
    },
    title: gw,
    description: 'Hosted By: ' + user,
  }
});
message.delete();
         }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I add some code formating for you.

`bot.on('message')` return only `message` object, you can't add some other variables.
For delete initial message, you can use `message.delete()`

Use [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) :) to learn methods of libery

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '?';
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', `${bot.user.username} is online on ${bot.guilds.cache.size} servers!`);
});

bot.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
    let cmd = args.shift();
    switch (cmd) {
        case 'gw':
            let gw = args.join(' ');
            let thumb = args[0];
            let date = new Date();
            let smallDate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + ' | ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            embed.setDescription(`Hosted By: ${message.author}`);
            embed.setColor(16580705);
            embed.setFooter(`Started On :  ${smallDate}`); //Better use embed.setTimestamp(), because its will convert time yo user local timezone
            embed.setTitle(gw);
            await message.channel.send(`\n <@&${'806183931065401405'}>` + `\n` + `\n  __**Giveaway**__ `, embed)
            await message.delete()
    }
});
```